# Android app: is it possible to inject script into web browser

Tags: javascript, android

I want to create an app which is able to inject a javascript script into a web page when the user clicks an item in the share menu (alternative methods of triggering the app to do this may also be ok).

I've found that adding an item into the share menu is pretty easy using the `ACTION_SEND` intent.

However, I've done a lot of googling and searching SO, but I can't seem to find any examples of people injecting scripts into an Android web browser, which is why I'm starting to doubt if this is possible.

Essentially, I have a bookmarklet which in injects javascript into whatever web page you're looking at. I want to build an app which does exactly the same as the bookmarklet does. Any alternative suggestions for achieving this would also be interesting to hear.

Comment: If there were a way to do this, it would be a hacker's paradise.

Comment: I'm using loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); in the onPageFinished method to inject the code needed to start a video on a web page, so yeah, it's possible to inject Javascript in a loaded web page.

Comment: @AleksG bookmarklets can do this, is there any additional security risk in it being triggered via user selecting from the share menu as opposed to user selecting bookmarklet?

Comment: Bookmarklet is execute via a direct action by a user.  When a user runs an app, the user doesn't expect it to run JS in the browser.

Comment: @soupy1976 Hey, did you find any solution to this? I am working on similar lines and unable to find any way to go ahead

Comment: @labyrinth unfortunately not yet, although I haven't really got back to looking at it yet. It is possible in iOS apps ( >= iOS8), we've successfully done that. If I manage it in Android, will update this Q. Unlikely to look at it again for a while though.

Comment: In case of iOS8, which browser have you managed to inject a script? Any source I can check for reference?

Comment: @labyrinth - soupy1976 is talking about an iOS App Extension Action for Safari. You can find out the specifics with an example in the "Accessing a Webpage" section of the Apple App Extension Programming Guide Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1

Comment: Long time ago, but any updates on this? Trying to Share page HTML to my app by injecting JS. Did this on iOS no problem.

Comment: @tallen11 actually our requirement to do this disappeared, as we decided on a different approach, so I can't help I'm afraid